# Entropy for Nonce creation

Tags: security, random, oauth, cryptography

In [OAuth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849), a Nonce is used to prevent replay-attacks. In addition to the nonce, a timestamp is also used (and can be considered a second nonce, as, when strictly sticking with the specification, there is no timeframe in which requests are consideed valid - servers MAY, not MUST limit the range).

The question that came into my mind when implementing a OAuth-Client is: Do Nonces have to be cryptographcally secure?

Two points are important to me here:

1. Is it ok to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` and risk predictable values if the system is running low on entropy when many nonces are created in little time?
   (For those not familiar with random/urandom: This would have an advantage in performance, as `/dev/urandom` doesn't block calls when little entropy is available at the cost of security, as, of course, values are less random).
2. As nonces have to be encoded to be sent if they contain non-ASCII-characters, it's the easiest thing to create them only out of those ASCII chars that can be sent as-is ([0-9A-Za-z_-+~] AFAIR). Of course this limits entropy again, so the nonce has t be longer to be equally strong. In your oppinion, what's a reasonable length for nonce that only consist of those characters and is it worth the advantage of not having to encode?

Comment: "Nonce" stands for "number used once". Typically nonces need not be random or unpredictable, but only unique. Randomly generating them is simply the easiest way to make them unique (unless a collision occurs, but with negligible probability). I can't speak for OAuth though as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Thanks for your comment. Basically that'S how I thought it is, so thanks for confirming. Collission is not a real problem, I'm appending microsekonds to the nonce, chances that there aer still collissions are nearly zero. (BUt appending them makes the last 6 characters predictable, so if it had to be unpredictable, this would be another issue)

Comment: A system can't run low on entropy because many nonces are created. It can only run low because it hasn't been seeded *yet*. A secure PRNG doesn't become weak just because you read a lot from it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos AFAIK /dev/ranbom uses input from external sources (mouse movement, network, etc) to seed the PRNG. ANd it CAN run low on new input.

Comment: @CodesInChaos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux, second paragraph.

Comment: `/dev/random` aims for information theoretical security, so it can block. But if you're content with computational security, you can take one truly random 256 bit seed and stretch it into as much output as you like. As long as the cipher you use to do that is secure, the output is secure as well. This is essentially how `/dev/urandom` works. It can only transition from insecure (not yet sufficiently seeded) to secure (seeded with enough entropy). Once it's in a secure state it can output unlimited amounts of secure, unpredictable data without running out of entropy.

Comment: ...which brings us to the entire point of the quesiton: AM I content with computational security, or am I not? 'cause I don't know. (I guess I am, but I wanted to make sure, 'cause this is about authenticating requests on truly sensitive data...)

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is hardly ever useful to use `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`. You can make a point of using it to seed other PRNG's if you don't want to have those PRNG's rely on `/dev/urandom`. For nonce's, you should certainly be better off using `/dev/urandom`. Or you can use a well seeded, thread local cryptographically secure PRNG implemented in your app or library of course.

If you want to send a nonce (or most binary data) over ASCII then you can use [hexadecimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) or [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). For the best readability of the value itself, use hex, for efficiency use base64. Now by default base 64 uses numbers, upper and lowercase letters, plus the characters `+`, `/` and `=` but if you want to use other values you can always URLencode the base64, replace the characters you do not want, or use [one of the variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history).

Comment: As for encoding, OAuth permits different characters than default URLEncode, = is not allowed unencoded - and URLencoding is just another unnecessary step. Therefore, base64 isn't an alternative. FOr the moment, I just have an array with all chars that can be sent unencoded and chose randomly from them for each char.

Comment: You need to have a power of two to convert to and from bit arrays. Although it is possible to use more characters, chances are that your result won't be fully random. It's much better to simply generate a true random array of a certain size and replace the `?` and `=` characters if these are not allowed.

Comment: That, again, depends on the level of randomness I really need, which is the ntire question. If strength is importantn, than yes, you're right (I never thought about that, thanks!). If I don'T, it'S still right but irrelevant ;)

Comment: Nonces even in name do not need to be cryptographically secure. But it is easiest to make them cryptographically secure if you don't want to keep state. Of course, in that case the nonce size must be big enough. Now you do not have to use a cryptographically secure RNG, and you don't need to assure that every bit is as random as the other. But e.g. hash based RNG's don't need to be very slow, and base 64 is probably more efficient than schemes that do not keep to bit boundaries.